# MySql object linking

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have question which might be quite simple, but I am not sure what is the best answer.

I have a table (object 1) that needs to be related to a couple of different tables (other objects). So I see 2 ways of doing it. Either create one linking table which holds:

**lnkObject1Objects**

- lnkObjectObjectId - PK
- object1Id - FK (required field)
- object2Id - FK (not required field)
- object3Id - FK (not required field)
- object4Id - FK (not required field)

So in this case field object1Id is only filled out, but only one of fields object2-4Id is filled out.

The second solution that I see is to create 3 different linking tables

**lnkObject1Object2**

- lnkObject1Object2Id - PK
- ObjectId1 - FK (required)
- ObjectId2 - FK (required)

**lnkObject1Object3**

- lnkObject1Object3Id
- PK ObjectId1 FK (required)
- ObjectId3 - FK (required)

**lnkObject1Object4**

- lnkObject1Object4Id
- PK ObjectId1 - FK (required)
- ObjectId4 - FK (required)

I favor the first option, since for programming this might be easier, but for database design the second solution is better. Do I miss any other great solution? Or is there a big argument to use for one or the other?

Answer (score -1):

you can create one table with type column to maintain all your object linked with object 1 as below

[image]

it will be ideal because there is no null values in DB.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, but then you cannot create a foreign key on the otherObjectId column, because it can be mapped to multiple tables